# Average gap of a sorted sequence.

Tags: recursive-algorithms

Considering a sorted sequence $a_0\leq a_1\leq...\leq a_{n-1}$ and defining the average gap of any subsequence to be:-

$f(i,j)=\frac{(aj-ai)}{(j-i)}$,

I would like to show that for all $ i=1,...,n-2$ it holds that either $f(0,i)\geq f(0,n-1)$ or $f(i,n-1)\geq f(0,n-1)$.

I am looking to prove this by contradiction, so I have assumed that $f(0,i)$ and $f(i,n-1)$ are both < $f(0,n-1)$.

Where should I proceed? Does anybody know how to prove this?

Comment: Hint: $(n-1)f(0,n-1)=if(0,i)+(n-i-1)f(i,n-1)$.

Comment: Thank you I've got it now!